# Why new sailjs project has terrible response times during load testing

Tags: node.js, sails.js, load-testing

I tried load testing our site with terrible results, so I decided to try load test a new ("out of the box") sailsjs project with no changes other than local.js port (8080) and environment mode (production). We are using Google Cloud platform for both site hosting and load testing. The site resources can easily handle the requests:

```
30% cpu usage - Disk I/O 16k bytes/sec - ram < 10% - no db used
```

The average and max response times, in milliseconds:

```
250 users:
Avg 10
Max 89

500 users: 
Avg 10   
Max 122 

750 users:
Avg 26
Max 847

1000 users:
Avg 50 (but starts jumping faster from this point) 
Max 3000

2000 users:
Avg 700
Max 6400

2500 user:
Avg 1115
Max 7611

4000 users:
Avg 3030
Max 10370
```

Is there possibly some bottleneck created because of a limit of 1 thousand, because that's when the bad delays start?

When I try profiling, the major part of the delay is given as (idle).

Sailsjs out of the box seems to be no where near the hundreds of thousands of concurrent users others have achieved, with good response times.

Comment: Is there a cluster of multiple nodes or a single node? Also, how many requests per second you get in each test?

Comment: Cluster of multiple nodes, two nodes of Googles machince type standard-n2 in this case. (i've tried 10 nodes but still not a great result-much of a change). Can't remember the exact req/sec, but around 10 req/sec for every 100 users but it hit a limit of around 200 req/sec. @WiktorZychla